# Rename multiple files using Node JS

Tags: node.js, file, rename, require

I just started learning Node JS and I don't know how to solve this:

I have a folder with 291 files, and I want to rename all those 291 items in order, with a title that I've saved in an Array. This is an example of the array:

```
let arrayTitles = [`1-name of file`,
`2-name of file`,
`3-name of file`]
```

I know i need to use `.rename()` or `.renameSync()`, and also maybe a forEach or for loop, but I don't know how.

This is what I tried:

```
const fs = require(`fs`)
const filesNames = fs.readdirSync(`./imgs`)

for(let i=0; i<filesNames.length; i++){
    filesNames[i] = fs.renameSync(filesNames[i], newArr[i])
}
```

I know it's way off but I don't know how to access the elements of the array and rename the current `i` of the file which name I'm trying to change.
Also I've read something about a path of the `.renameSync()` function but as I'm leaning on my own I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Construct full paths for both the existing and new filenames and pass those to `fs.renameSync()`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, that's why I'm here lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass complete file path in `renameSync()`. you can achive this by

```
fs.renameSync(
__dirname + '/imgs/' + filesNames[i],
__dirname + '/imgs/' + newArr[i]
```

);
but remember in linux and windows path separator are different for ex:-

on windows:- `F:\myproject\1b2`

on Linux:- `F/myproject/1b2`

to resolve this i would recommend to use `path.sep`  which works according to os, read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathsep).

i have created a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-grrs28?file=index.js) please upvote/select if helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for, except I've modified some things, this is how it ended up:

`filesNames[i] = fs.renameSync('./imgs/'+filesNames[i], './imgs/'+newArr[i])`

I tried something like this `F:\myproject\1b2` to select a dir, but it didn't work. Thank you!!

Comment: Just use `path.join()` and it will handle the path separator for you automatically.